# How to Determine the Cron Job or Any identifier in the Running Model

Tags: cron

Let's say we have this, `sales/observer::aggregateSalesReportBestsellersData` run model in the cron, how can we determine the `job_code` (in this case, `aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data`) when the function run?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the cron is running or not you can do it through shell using command `crontab -l`

Moreover, to see the specific cron job running in Magento you can use the free extension [AOE Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html). It will give you detailed information regarding the tasks running.